# Does the も particle always act on the word just before it?

Tags: particle-も

イギリスでは土曜日はもとより金曜の午後まで休みにしている会社**も**ある。
Translation is:

1. In the UK, some companies are closed on Saturdays **as well as Friday** afternoons.

<sub>In the English version, 'as well as' acts on 'Friday afternoon' i.e 'as well as starting from friday after noon,the companies close'.</sub>

2. In the Japanese version:
   the word-by-word translation of the sentence looks to me like:
   In England, not just Saturday, but there **there are also companies where until Friday afternoon a rest is made**.

From what i understood from the sentence, the **も** must relate between 'Saturday' and 'Until Friday afternoon' *NOT* '土曜日' and '金曜の午後まで休みにしている会社'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> '<s>Until</s> Friday afternoon'

The まで used here means "even", not "until".

<sub>も can mean "even" too, as well as "also". 「[relative clause]+XXもある」 is usually translated as "There are some XXs that [relative clause]" →
"Some XXs do..."</sub>

> ［土曜日**はもとより**金曜の午後**まで**休みにしている］会社もある。

Whole 土曜日はもとより金曜の午後まで休みにしている is a relative clause that modifies 会社.

「～はもとより‥まで」= "even ‥ not just ~" ≂「～はもちろん‥まで」「～だけでなく‥まで」「～はもちろん‥(まで)も」

*lit.* "There are also/even companies [which make **not only** Saturday **but even** Friday afternoon off]"
→ Some companies are closed even on Friday afternoons, not just Saturdays.